# Why is the OCaml type conversion function named in the form "A_of_B"?

Tags: ocaml, naming

The name like "A_of_B" is a unique naming convention in OCaml, but I want to know why. Is it a result of the different language usage between French and English? Or Xavier Leroy's personal preference?

Background: I found that OCaml's type conversion functions have the name like `A_of_B`, for example, `int_of_string : string -> int` or `float_of_int : int -> float` in Stdlib module. Other popular languages use the name like `AtoB`, for example, `itoa` function in C.

Comment: This question belongs on english.stackexchange or french.stackexchange. The closest construction I know is the genitive of material ("river of honey," "statue of marble") found in Latin.

Comment: I think it's also related to which module has the definition, in the module for integers you would have `int_of_string` and `int_to_string` for instance. If those functions were defined in a module for strings you would have `string_of_int` and `string_to_int`.

Comment: For things that are not in Pervasives it's Foo.of_Bar and Foo.to_Bar. But the core types don't have their own modules so the module scope is replaced by type_.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, let's start with a short excursus to the [history of OCaml](http://caml.inria.fr/about/history.en.html). Xavier Leroy didn't invent the language and neither the language was born in France. OCaml was born from the Meta Language (ML) of the [LCF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_for_Computable_Functions) (Logic for Computable Functions) theorem prover, developed in Stanford and University of Edinburgh by [Robin Milner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_Milner). Below is a snippet of code, obtained from the original LCF 1977,

```
   let gensrinfo th =
     let srthm = disjsrvars th in 
     let hypfrees = formlfrees(hyp srthm)
     and hyptyvars = formltyvars(hyp srthm)
     and (),p,() = destimpequiv(concl srthm) in 
     srthm , termmatch(hypfrees,hyptyvars) p;;
```

Does it resemble something? ;) It was a little bit later when the French Formel team developed a new *implementation* of ML, based on the Categorical Abstract Machine, that later turned into SML, and Caml itself was born 10 years later than the code snippet above in 1987. And three years later, in 1990, Xavier Leroy designed a completely new *implementation* of Caml based on a bytecode interpreter called ZINC. Five years later, they developed an optimizing compiler, and five more years later, in 2000, Objective Caml was born, aka O'Caml and, now, OCaml.

This is all to say that, originally, ML was designed and developed by the English-speaking community and there is no justification to search for the convention etymology in the French language or Xavier's preferences. We, indeed, can find this convention already in LCF (e.g., `intoftok`, `tokofint` operators) and in other derivatives of LCF, such as HOL, e.g., the HOL 1988 standard library already had the function [int_of_string](https://www.cs.utah.edu/%7Eswalton//hol98/help/Docfiles/HTML/hol88Lib.int_of_string.html), at that time Xavier didn't even graduate yet.

So, why this convention? It comes from the way of reasoning about programs, which is logical rather than imperative (remember, ML was born as a meta-language (the logic language) in a theorem prover). Instead of thinking about *how* a function is implemented, we are thinking about *what* the term represents, so what is `int_of_string "42"`? It is an integer, that has textual representation "42". We do not *convert* "42" into an integer and think about it as a transformation box, instead, we employ [declarative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming) thinking as in mathematics, e.g., `cos 0.0` doesn't convert `0.0` into `1.0`, `cos 0.0` *is* `1.0`. This style of thinking facilitates [equational reasoning](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Edpw/courses/cos326-12/notes/reasoning.php) -- a powerful way of thinking about programs and understanding their semantics.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that it is intended to be more readable when working with functions as values, e.g. with higher-order functions like function composition:

```
# let compose f g = fun x -> f (g x);;
val compose : ('a -> 'b) -> ('c -> 'a) -> 'c -> 'b = <fun>
```

Here, composition is reflected directly in names:

```
# let string_of_float = compose string_of_int int_of_float;;
val string_of_float : float -> string = <fun>
```

Whereas it could be a bit hard to read the equivalent with functions names with the reverse order:

```
compose int_to_string float_to_int
```